# (Google Docs) A browser error has occurred. Please hold the Shift key and click the Refresh button to try again

Tags: firefox, google-drive-api

I get this error on Firefox 24.0, and I have firebug, fireftp and colorzilla installed.  This just started happening recently.  I have searched for this problem but all the topics come up as being from 2-4 years back, mostly Firefox versions 3 through 4.

Anyone have an idea how to fix this?  They work in IE OK.

This also appears to do this for the main list page:
https://drive.google.com/?pli=1&authuser=0#
that just hangs without showing ANY of my docs.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for weeks.
Finally what resolved it is pretty stupid... Not sure if it will work again.
But maybe it will help someone!

Instead of going to drive.google.com I just opened docs.google.com and after it forwarded me to drive everything started to work... without even a cache clean!

Pretty funny!?

Comment: not sure if it was because of your suggestion or not, but I appear to be up and running on google docs again..  Thanks!